# Why does SUM used in row context (calculated column) sum the entire column when it only has access to the row?

Tags: powerbi, dax

In a row context, the formula can see only what is in the current row.

So when I use SUM(tbl[col]) in a calculated column, then why does it sum the whole column?

Comment: Can you provide a tabular example? And expand a bit more about your question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you call SUM in a row context, it is not getting evaluated in the row context, it is getting evaluated in the filter context, meaning the column inside SUM isn't referring to the currently iterated row, if you want to get the correct result you need wrap SUM inside CALCULATE so that CALCULATE can initiate Context Transition and that will convert the currently iterated row into an equivalent filter context.

Comment: 1) I think it isn't right to say that it is getting evaluated in f ilter context. Because there is no filter context. Hence it is doing the sum on the whole column. 2) also it is indeed getting evaluated in the row context. But in absence of filter context. Are these 2 points I am making right?

Comment: Filter context is always there it is just that either it is empty or it contains something, but yes for the purpose of understanding you can think that there is no filter context.